# Implied string comparison, 0=='', but 1=='1'

Tags: javascript

I was debugging something and discovered some strangeness in JavaScript:

```
alert(1=='') ==> false
alert(0=='') ==> true
alert(-1=='') ==> false
```

It would make sense that an implied string comparison that 0 should = '0'. This is true for all non-zero values, but why not for zero?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the Mozilla documentation on [Javascript Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

> If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the
>   operands then applies strict
>   comparison. If either operand is a
>   number or a boolean, the operands are
>   converted to numbers; if either
>   operand is a string, the other one is
>   converted to a string

What's actually happening is that the strings are being converted to numbers.
For example:

`1 == '1'` becomes `1 == Number('1')` becomes `1 == 1`: `true`

Then try this one:
`1 == '1.'` becomes `1 == Number('1.')` becomes `1 == 1`: `true`
If they were becoming strings, then you'd get `'1' == '1.'`, which would be false.

It just so happens that `Number('') == 0`, therefore `0 == ''` is true

Answer (score 10):

When javascript does implicit type conversions, the empty string literal will match the 0 integer.  Do your comparison like this and you'll get your expected result:

```
alert(1==='') ==> false
alert(0==='') ==> false
alert(-1==='') ==> false
```

Answer (score 4):

ECMA-262, 3rd edition, 11.9.3 regarding `x == y`, step 16:

> If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

The empty string `''` gets converted to `0` before the comparison.

Comment: @RoBorg: linking doesn't work with PDFs, and googling ECMA-262 and clicking the first link isn't that much of an inconvenience..

Comment: @Christoph neither is googling for "javascript equality operator" but that's not the point

Comment: @RoBorg: my point was that it's *impossible* to deep link to the correct section, and providing a link to a readily available standards document isn't really one of my priorities - so what *is* your point?

Answer (score 3):

This is just one of the truly hideous mangles that went into the JavaScript compromise. '' and 0 are both uninitialized values (equal to boolean false) and, therefore, equal.

To protect yourself from weird bugs like this, it's better to always use the === operator.

Comment: 0 and '' are not uninitialized values. They are values that are implicitly type converted to the same value when compared.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript, like PHP, is weakly typed*. So when you compare 0 to '', the JS engine converts them to a similar datatype. Since 0 and '' both equate to boolean(false), "false == false" is true.

*Weakly typed languages do not require variables to be any specific data type, so you can set one variable as a string, change it to int, float, and back to string without the processor throwing errors.

Comment: +1 Very  nice - do you know how the engine decides which datatype to convert to?  Obviously converting 0 to a string would not have the same results.

Comment: This is wrong - '' will be converted to 0, not boolean `false`

Comment: No, I'm not sure. I would suspect that it's a numerical type, or a boolean cast.

Comment: I don't think this explanation is accurate. Both 0 and '' are not converted to false before the comparison. See RoBorg's answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462663/implied-string-comparison-0-but-11#462713]

Comment: check my answer - I looked it up, and the standard says the string will be converted to number!

Comment: @Christoph - I  didn't mean that they are converted to booleans, I meant that they are converted to similar types. And they also equate to false.

Comment: @davethegr8: it might be true that they both evaluate to false in boolean contexts, but what relevance does this have to the question?

Comment: That on some level, they are equivalent. I wasn't certain of the details, but there's a much better explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462663/implied-string-comparison-0-but-11#462713

Answer (score 2):

In many languages, the empty string can be coerced to false.

Beware of doing comparisons with == instead of ===:

```
alert('' == '0'); //false  
alert(0 == ''); // true  
alert(0 =='0'); // true
```

== is not transitive.