# Why javascript treats 0 equal to empty string?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implied string comparison, 0='', but 1='1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462663/implied-string-comparison-0-but-1-1)

Executing the following case in javascript, I get 0 equal to '' (an empty string)

```
var a   =   0;
var b   =   '';//empty string
if(a==b){
    console.log('equal');//this is printed in console
}else{
    console.log('not equal');
}
```

Could anyone guide that what is the reason behind this?

Comment: (typeof a == typeof b && a == b) to check if they are identical
(a === b) to check if they are the same if a and b points to the same object in memory

Comment: use code if(a===b) return correct result

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Quoting the doc ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)):

> **Equal (==)**
>
> If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the
>   operands then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number
>   or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if possible; else
>   if either operand is a string, the other operand is converted to a
>   string if possible.

As `a` operand type here is `Number`, `b` gets converted to Number as well. And `Number('')` evaluates to `0`.

This can be quite surprising sometimes. Consider this, for example:

```
console.log(0 == '0');  // true
console.log(0 == '');   // true
console.log('' == '0'); // O'RLY?
```

... or this:

```
console.log(false == undefined); // false
console.log(false == null);      // false
console.log(null == undefined);  // fal.... NO WAIT!
```

...and that's exactly why it's almost always recommended to use `===` (strict equality) operator instead.

Comment: Thanks for the details shared. type comparison definitely should be the preferred choice. But in our case, we had a challenge that this comparison was taking place in a function receiving values as arguments and user could pass 1 as '1' too which is permissible in javscript. In such a case, if we use type comparison then '1' would not be equal to 1. Due to this, we had to avoid type comparison. Don't know what can be the safest method for this?

Comment: @netemp I'd suggest using `parseInt(arg, 10)` construct. When `arg` is a string, it will be _parsed_ into number (and it's more consistent then `Number(arg)`), and when `arg` is a number, it'll get back to you unharmed. )

Comment: Thankyou. Wasn't aware the type conversion was achieved using Number (which unlike parseInt does not return NaN in the case of '' or ' '). Answer also helped explain this for me, why: '' == 0 && ' ' == 0 // true. Yet: !!' ' == !!0 // false. With the latter the type conversion is done to each argument first (rather than the arguments either side of ==) therefore '  ' evaluates to truthy.

Answer (score 5):

`0`, `""` (Empty String), `false` all technically have the same value, when typecasted. If you need to strictly treat them, you can use `===`.

It is the same with similar programming languages, like PHP.

```
var a = 0;
var b = ''; //empty string
if(a == b){
    console.log('equal'); //this is printed in console
}else{
    console.log('not equal');
}
```

#### To make a strict comparison:

```
if(a === b){
    console.log('equal');
}else{
    console.log('not equal'); //this is printed in console
}
```

Comment: "It is the same with any programming language." Not true. BTW, I am not downvoter.

Comment: `0 null "" are all same` is a funny statement. And so is `It is the same with any programming language`. That said, I'd say your answer is correct, but inaccurate.

Comment: Well, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Also the implication that 0==null & ''==null is not correct

Comment: @AlexK. Corrected. :) Should have been `false` not `null`. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not the one, but your answer is still a bit incorrect. See, you get the same value - 0 - when casting `0`, `""` and `false` to `Number`. But it's the same with string `'0'` (and `'  0  '`, and even `' \r\n '`, for example), first. And casting `0` and `false` to `String` will give you totally different results. So no, they do not have the same _value_.

Comment: I (the downvoter if I didn't make it clear last time) removed the downvote. Though, you should be more specific about what you typecast it to and I think saying that something is similar to PHP may be offending :)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Sure thanks. Will take care. And sorry if I had been rude.

Answer (score 2):

`==` operator in javascript don't compare types so `0=='' === true` (because as a number string `''` evaluates to 0) or `0==false === true` (because bool `false` evaluates to `0`) to compare types to you can use `===` operator.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) you'll find useful information about comparison.

Answer (score 1):

== does typecasting. *Always* use ===.

In your example, the empty string of b is being converted to 0. So both a and b are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Because empty string represented as number is zero. If you compare apples and oranges you should think of how your particular orange would look if it were an apple.

Answer (score 1):

Because `==` checks value equality so `false`, `0` and empty strings are equals. Use identity check `===`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript automatically converts variables of different types for comparison. That's a common feature in non-strictly typed languages.

If you need to compare variables and check the type, use the `===` operator.

Answer (score 0):

In most programming language(including javascript) `""`(string), `0`(integer), `\x0`(null) losely mean the same thing: "empty". What's happening is your javascript engine finds `"" == 0` false, due to the `==` it converts `0` to an integer. Again this is false, so it converts `0` to null which is false, so then it converts `0` to an empty string. (Not sure if this is the correct order of conversion). To make the condition "exact" match(no conversion) use `===` inplace of `==`

Answer (score 0):

Because of coercion. It is usually a better idea to use `===` for comparisons in JavaScript.