# Delete a row in Google Spreadsheets if value of cell in said row is 0

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm working on a script to search my Google Sheet for 0 on E Column and then delete the row, so far I have this:

```
function readRows() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
    var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
    var values = rows.getValues();

    var rowsDeleted = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
        var row = values[i];
        if (row[4] == 0) {
            sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i) + 1) - rowsDeleted);
            rowsDeleted++;
        }
    }
}
```

But this script delete rows with blank values as well I want to ignore these blank values

Comment: I don't have experience with Spreadsheets, but is there a difference between null and 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison `row[4] == 0` will return TRUE when the value is exactly `0` and anything evaluating to `0`, in which case is a blank string.

Use strict equality checking to achieve the result you're after:

```
if (row[4] === 0) {
```

See also:

- [Why javascript treats 0 equal to empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422064/why-javascript-treats-0-equal-to-empty-string)
- [Implied string comparison, 0='' but 1='1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462663/implied-string-comparison-0-but-1-1)
- [Comparison operators | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity)