# does number zero work as " " in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document.getElementById("Btn1").onclick = function() {
  var aa = document.getElementById("fInput").value;
  var a = Number(aa);
  var bb = document.getElementById("sInput").value;
  var b = Number(bb);
  if (a == "" || b == "") {
    alert("Fill both inputs");
  } else if (a < 1 || a > 3 || b < 1 || b > 3) {
    alert(" Fields can only contain values ' 1 & 2 & 3 ' ");
  } else if (a == b) {
    alert("Not Possible !!");
  } else {
    var myArray = ['frBox', 'snBox', 'thirdBox'];
    var id1 = myArray[a - 1];
    var id2 = myArray[b - 1];
    Swap(id1, id2);
  }
}

function Swap(id1, id2) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id1).innerHTML;
  var y = document.getElementById(id2).innerHTML;
  document.getElementById(id1).innerHTML = y;
  document.getElementById(id2).innerHTML = x;
}
```

```css
.fBox {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: green;
}

.sBox {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: aqua;
  color: black;
}

.thBox {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: rgba(23, 84, 244, 0.4);
  color: rgb(45, 65, 77);
}

button {
  height: auto;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: crimson;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="fBox" id="frBox">
    <p>
      Hello From the first box.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="sBox" id="snBox">
    <p>
      JavaScript is Cool !!!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="thBox" id="thirdBox">
    <p>
      I am Learning JavaScript !!!
    </p>
  </div><br>
  <input id="fInput" placeholder="Num 1">
  <input id="sInput" placeholder="Num 2"><br><br>
  <button id="Btn1"> Click to Swap </button>
</body>

</html>
```

When I enter 0 in any of the inputs and a number between 1 and 3 in the other input and click on the button, it alerts "Fill both inputs".
But I expected seeing " Fields can only contain values ' 1 & 2 & 3 ' " alert.
or when I fill both inputs with 0, this issue again happens!!
Does 0 work as "" in JavaScript or there is a problem in my code??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why javascript treats 0 equal to empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422064/why-javascript-treats-0-equal-to-empty-string)

Answer (score 1):

0 and "" both evaluate to `false` in Javascript.

```
var x = 0;
if (x) {
  console.log('Will not be called.');
}

var y = '';
if (y) {
  console.log('Will not be called.');
}
```

As some of the other answers have alluded to, there is also lazy vs strict equality, using `==` vs `===`.

That wont fix your problem though, because you're doing `var a = Number(aa);`. If you enter `0` in one of your inputs, you'll get `Number(0)`, which is `0`. If you don't enter anything in one of your inputs, you'll get `Number('')`, which is `0`.

I'd replace

```
if (a == "" || b == "") { ... }
```

with

```
if (!a || !b) { ... }
// shorthand version of (if a === false || b === false)
// which will be the case if a or b === 0
```

If `0` is entered in either input, or if either input is left empty, you'll end up with `a` or `b` being `0`, which will evaluate to false.

Answer (score 0):

#### Shortly:

If you use `==`, **yes**.
To avoid it, use `===`.

#### Longer:

`==` (double equals) does some weird things because

- it tries to transform values to same types (in this case, to numbers), and
- `Number("") === 0`

#### Conclusion:

It's better to use [Strict equality operator (`===`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity) instead:

```js
document.getElementById("Btn1").onclick = function() {
  var aa = document.getElementById("fInput").value;
  var a = Number(aa);
  var bb = document.getElementById("sInput").value;
  var b = Number(bb);
  if (aa===""||bb==="") {
    alert("Fill both inputs");
  } else if (a < 1 || a > 3 || b < 1 || b > 3) {
    alert(" Fields can only contain values ' 1 & 2 & 3 ' ");
  } else if (a == b) {
    alert("Not Possible !!");
  } else {
    var myArray = ['frBox', 'snBox', 'thirdBox'];
    var id1 = myArray[a - 1];
    var id2 = myArray[b - 1];
    Swap(id1, id2);
  }
}

function Swap(id1, id2) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id1).innerHTML;
  var y = document.getElementById(id2).innerHTML;
  document.getElementById(id1).innerHTML = y;
  document.getElementById(id2).innerHTML = x;
}
```

```css
.fBox {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: green;
}

.sBox {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: aqua;
  color: black;
}

.thBox {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: rgba(23, 84, 244, 0.4);
  color: rgb(45, 65, 77);
}

button {
  height: auto;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: crimson;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="fBox" id="frBox">
    <p>
      Hello From the first box.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="sBox" id="snBox">
    <p>
      JavaScript is Cool !!!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="thBox" id="thirdBox">
    <p>
      I am Learning JavaScript !!!
    </p>
  </div><br>
  <input id="fInput" placeholder="Num 1">
  <input id="sInput" placeholder="Num 2"><br><br>
  <button id="Btn1"> Click to Swap </button>
</body>

</html>
```

#### See more information

- [Comparision of comparision operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#A_model_for_understanding_equality_comparisons)
- [`==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using)
- [`===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Strict_equality_using)